# Regex to get all numbers of any type

Tags: javascript, regex, exponent

I have strings like this:

> "1 -2 -0.00529366960223319 -1.72662226752857E-5 some text"

And I want to parse the numbers to an array, removing text, using javascript, to return this:

```
[1, -2, -0.00529366960223319, -1.72662226752857E-5]
```

I tried lots of expression, like the following:

> /[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/

without success, any help?

thanks in advance!

Comment: [It seems working](https://regex101.com/r/aN4fD4/1). Also, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j145qq9b/)

Comment: My approach: `-?[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?(?:E-[0-9]+)?`

Comment: You can do this without regex: `"1 -2 -0.00529366960223319 -1.72662226752857E-5 some text".split(' ').map(function (item) { var i = parseFloat(item); return isNaN(i) ? undefined : i; }).filter(function (item) { return typeof item !== 'undefined'; });`

Comment: `.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '').split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean).map(parseFloat)`

Comment: @adeneo That removes the exponent `E-5`

Comment: @Oriol - indeed it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex: `/[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?/g`

You was almost there.
Remember to escape all the special signs like `.` if you literally want it, or it will match with any character.
The `g` at end of regex enable the *global* matches.

```
var src = "+1 -2 -0.00529366960223319 -1.72662226752857E-5 some text 25e46";

var reg = /[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?/g;

res = src.match(reg);

// The matches are in elements 0 through n.
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "submatch " + i + ": " +  res[i] + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for this:

```
function isNumeric(n) {  /* http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/1529630 */
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
var str = "1 -2 -0.00529366960223319 -1.72662226752857E-5 some text",
    arr = str.split(" ").filter(isNumeric).map(Number);
```

Comment: `!isNaN(n)` is sufficient, no reason to bring `parseFloat` into the equation when it casts differently than `Number` would.

Comment: @zzzzBov But e.g. `!isNaN('\t') === true`, so `parseFloat` is needed. Or maybe I could split with `/\s+/` to remove these cases.

Comment: `Number('\t') === 0`, which is a number.